# How do you play an audio clip on a collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a sound clip play when my player collides with a specific obstacle. I created an AudioSource on the obstacle, and wrote this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
 public class sound : MonoBehaviour {


    AudioSource audioSource;

    void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)  
    {
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        Debug.Log("hit");

        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();

    }

}
```

I gave the player a tag "Player", but when they collide, even though they both have a 2Dcollider component, the collision is not registered. There is no sound, nor does it say "hit" in the debug.log statement I wrote to check.

I have looked on the Unity documentation and I don't see what I'm doing wrong - what am I missing?

Comment: Put your Log in front of the if-statement. Does it show "hit" now? If not, there is something wrong with how your colliders are set up. If it does, then there is something wrong with your tags. Also, if you are using 2D colliders then you need to use OnCollisionEnter2D

Answer (score 1):

When working in a 2D environment with 2D component you need to use the 2D endings for some of your functions to work.
In your case you use

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision c)
```

But you need to use

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collission2D c)
```

Docs:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html

Further more you might aswell use your audioSource.Play() since you already set the variable to the component in your Start(). Instead of GetComponent().Play();

Comment: Also, OP needs to add curly braces to the`if` statement or there will be a log but no sound. This is not a problem now but will be after using your solution

Comment: Yea, nicely spotted :)

Answer (score 0):

If 3D,

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
  if(other.tag == "Player"){

          this.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
          Debug.Log("PLayed Sound!");

  }
}
```

Simple. Good Luck on whatever your doing!